# Can't generate Android .apk in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise

Tags: android, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to export the apk file from my Android project in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise. As far as I remember, in Visual Studio 2015 there was the option "Export Android Package (.apk)" under the "Build" menu only if the Release configuration had been selected. In Visual Studio 2017, instead I can't find that option anymore. Does anyone know what has changed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the *release* build configuration, then right click on the Android projet and choose *Archive...* in the contextual menu. Once the archive has been created, click on *Distribute* to start the APK wizard (wich will ask you for the keystore as usual)

Beware that if you click on *Open Folder* instead of *Distribute*, the explorer will show you a folder containing an **unsigned** APK, wich **can not** be installed on a device.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I really don't know how to create a keystore because I've never followed these steps to extract the .apk file since in Visual Studio 2015 it wasn't required.

Comment: I am not sure what you are talking about, Xamarin always needed a keystore to generate a non debug APK. Anyway you can create a new one [from the wizard](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/#Sign_the_APK)